# How to install a visual theme in dart-editor?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Ok so I found this: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ to get new themes.  But how do I get the dart editor to install them?  Also should I have got the XML theme or the EPF?

Comment: Ok so this is just a usability issue.  On my mac the visual-theme panel in preferences gives no indication that it might be able to scroll down (to where I can see the import button).
As far as the file format goes only XML are usable.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this plugin [Rainbow](https://github.com/HannesRammer/Rainbow) in action at [GAppsEngine](https://rainbow-dart.appspot.com).
He figured out how it works has some info in the README.md in his repo.
If you don't find all you need add a comment and I try to find the discussion in the Dart Google group where the Dart people explained it to him.

Comment: That is super cool.  I got it to work.  My problem was more about how to import themes into the editor.  I figured it out though.

Comment: Yeah, I thought he had some explanation somewhere about this too. Otherwise his tools would not make sense. Can you please post what you found out?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to switch from the Dart Editor to Eclipse with the [Dart Plugin](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/). The Dart Editor is simply Eclipse with the [Dart Plugin](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/) installed.

First, download the latest version of [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/). Then install the [Dart Plugin](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/). Next install the [Color Theme Plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin).

Now you can use themes and dart together! Make sure to switch to the Dart perspective before you start coding.